# Will 'page number' be in singular if use it with 'from'?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammatical-number

My sentence:

1. The teacher made us read from *page number* 10 *to* 15.
2. The teacher made us read from *page numbers* 10 *to* 15.

Which one above is correct?
Is the sentence above grammatically correct?
Should I use the plural of *page number* i.e. 'page numbers', as we are not talking about a single page here?
Which is more appropriate here- *to* or *up to*?

Comment: Ranges are normally specified from *[**the**] first* to *[**the**] last* (each "endpoint" being ***singular***). So if I didn't know it came from a non-native speaker, I'd assume your second example implied something different. Specifically, #1 *probably* means all of us were required to read the entire range of 6 pages (probably, *silently, to ourselves*), whereas I might interpret #2 as meaning that some or all of us where required to stand up in class and read *parts* of the specified range of text out loud (i.e. - the difference would mainly turn on ***read** to oneself / out loud*).

Comment: Note the different preposition usages in *He read **from** the book* (probably, ***to** his audience*) and *He read **from** page 1 **to** page 4*.

Comment: The shorter the better. The shortest is "... to read pages 10 to 15."

Answer (score 1):

Of the two alternatives sentence 1 is better. It would be clearer as *The teacher made us read from page number 10 to page number 15*, but your contraction is acceptable.

It is very common to leave out the word "number" in such sentences. This would change the first sentence to *The teacher made us read from page 10 to page 15*. Sentence 2 could be changed similarly to *The teacher made us read pages 10 to 15*.

In the first sentence we use singular (page or number) because it talks individually about the start (which is singular) and the end (which is also singular). A sentence talking about multiple pages needs to specify the range, like my version of sentence 2.

For sentence 1 you can use "to" or "up to"; it does not matter as pages are always read in numerical order. On the other hand "up to" does not work for sentence 2.

There are a couple of other issues with the second sentence. Firstly it can be misunderstood as a request to read only page numbers. Secondly the word "from" used with a range can mean a *selection* from the range as in *I read selected paragraphs from pages 10 to 15*.

Answer (score 0):

Teachers often say

> Turn to page 10
> Open your books on page 15

Adding "number" is redundant. We know that 10 and 15 are numbers.

When studying or reading aloud more than a single page, it's quite common to say or hear

> Read **pages** 10 **to** 15